# ORA-00936: отсутствует выражение ORA-06512: на

Tags: sql, oracle, процедуры

При выполнении ХП иногда появляется такая ошибка:

```
SQL> CALL MY_PROC();
CALL MY_PROC()
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: отсутствует выражение ORA-06512: на
"MY_USER.MY_PROC", line 22
ORA-06512: на  "MY_USER.MY_PROC", line 192
ORA-06512: на  "MY_USER.MY_PROC", line 224
```

В коде ничего особенного:

```
...
192 update_val_proc(l_id, l_time, l_key, l_code, l_type, l_price, l_no);
...
193 loop_through_table_proc(327746);    
224 write_log('done.');
...
```

Страно то, что на одних и тех же входных данных ХП иногда работает без ошибок, а иногда выдает эту ошибку. Как вывести дополнительную информацию об ошибке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORA-06512 это собственно не ошибка а сообщение о трассировке стека ошибки.

Ошибка это ORA-00936 - как правило это связано с тем, что одно из полей принимает значение `null` там где не положено.